# Penguin character in file

Tags: spacemacs, unicode

I use Spacemacs. I tried to type a command, but I mistyped. Instead of what I intended, a character was inserted that renders as this:
[image: a penguin of some sort?]

I suppose that is [Tux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tux_(mascot)). When I try to copy the character, I get this: .

1. How did this happen?
2. Is this behaviour documented anywhere?

I use the official `.spacemacs`, with little additions. This happened in `org-mode`, if that matters.

Comment: Interesting... can you tell us the command you 'tried' to type?

Comment: It's no doubt too late now, but for future reference know that `C-h l` shows some of the last keys and mouse actions you used.

Comment: @Drew: Thank you! It is too late indeed. I forgot what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we do not know what you typed (neither what you tried),
it is hard to know what happened.

You can insert it by typing `C-x 8 RET e000`.  (Note that this hexadecimal value is displayed within the [tofu](https://www.gammon.com.au/unicode/#missing-code-points) rendering for this character.)

About the character, only the font you use is relevant.
Some fonts show different symbols.

This character [`57344 (#o160000, #xe000)`]
is the first from [Private Use Area (PUA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas) plane 0
(U+E000-U+F8FF). Thus, it is not defined, it is not a Tux/Penguin char by definition,
if you want a [penguin char there is `128039 (#o372047, #x1f427)`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f427/index.htm)
(`C-x 8 RET 1f427` or `C-x 8 RET penguin`).